# Python - Convert Multiple Excelfiles to CSV and overwrite old rows

Tags: python, csv

Good Morning,
I am trying to convert multiple Excelfiles to CSV. Here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv 

counter = 0   
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".xlsm"):            
        if counter == 0:
            df_xlsmtocsv = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet2', index_col=None ) 
            df_xlsmtocsv .drop(df_xlsmtocsv .head(1).index,inplace=True) 

            print(df_qctocsv)
            with open('items.csv', 'w', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
                df_xlsmtocsv .to_csv(f, sep=',', header=None, index_label=None, index=False)
            counter += 1
        else:      
            df_xlsmtocsv = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet2', index_col=None, dtype = str)  
            df_xlsmtocsv .drop(df_xlsmtocsv .head(1).index,inplace=True)
            with open('items.csv', 'a', encoding = "utf-8") as f:

                df_xlsmtocsv .to_csv(f, sep=',', header=None, index_label=False, index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

How you can see I am able to list all xls-files in a folder and convert this to one csv. The files have this string-format:

```
005-72_b_linux_–_april_2017
005-73_a_linux_–_may_2017
005-75_b_linux_–_july_2017
005-76_d_linux_-_august_2017
```

The problem: If I have a row "X" in the file April-2017 and and the same updated row in may-2017 I want to overwrite the old row from april-2017 in the csv-file. But my solution above can not recognise files by month-string.

Comment: You will need to add some sample data to the question to make it clearer, e.g. example Excel rows and your expected CSV output.

Comment: A have simple rows: like 10023, Linux, Description

Comment: is there any identifier for the record that can identify the duplicate row?

Comment: Yes, first row is a number for example: (1001, Linux, V1.1, Description -> 1001, Linux, V1.1, Description Updated). Normally the list-function works from january till december. So best solution would be to overwrite duplicates or merge it and keep only newest one from next file.